# Validation.GetHasError always return true for WPF ValidationRule

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

I saw an good solution in order to test the validation of a group for contrôls :

**In my Window.xaml.cs :**

```
 private bool IsValid(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        // The dependency object is valid if it has no errors, 
        //and all of its children (that are dependency objects) are error-free.
        return !Validation.GetHasError(obj) &&
            LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj)
            .OfType<DependencyObject>()
            .All(child => IsValid(child));
    }
```

My problem is, in my case, even if i have error, isValid always return true.
I think is because of an xaml mistake but...where?

**Here is my Windows.XAML :**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CommandBinding x:Key="binding" Command="Save" Executed="Save_Executed" CanExecute="Save_CanExecute" />
</Window.Resources>

<TextBox Name="TextBox_TypeEvenement" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20">
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="strEvtType">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <ExceptionValidationRule />
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>

<Button Template="{StaticResource BoutonRessourcesTpl}" Command="Save">
  <Button.CommandBindings>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="binding"></StaticResource>
  </Button.CommandBindings>
  <Image Source= "Toolbar_Valider.png" Height="16"/>
</Button>
```

**And here is my Class.cs c# :**

```
private string m_strEvtType;
public string strEvtType
{
get { return m_strEvtType; }
set {
        m_strEvtType = value;
        if (m_objEvtCode.ReadEvtTypebyType(m_strEvtType) != 0)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(m_strEvtType.Trim() + " est innexistant !");
        }
        FirePropertyChangedEvent("strEvtType");
        FirePropertyChangedEvent("m_objEvtCode.strDes");
    }
}
```

Have you an idea why isValid always return true ?

Thanks a lot :)

Best regards :)

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the `throw`, does it ever get hit?

Comment: Yes, because, in my screen i saw the " error label" ;-)

Comment: Try replacing `.All(child => IsValid(child));` with `.Any(child => !IsValid(child));` as if there are no child DependencyObjects on the DependencyObject `All` will return true.

Comment: The Visual and Logical Trees can be surprising at times. The problem you might be having is that `GetChildren` is returning some objects that are not `DependencyObject`s and halting the recursion.

Comment: I have tried to replace     .All(child => IsValid(child));  by     .Any(child => !IsValid(child));  and no changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `All` usage in your `Linq`

> All will return true if every element of the source sequence passes
>   the test in the specified predicate, **or if the sequence is empty**;
>   otherwise, false.

So if there are no child `DependencyObjects` on the `DependencyObject` `All` will return true

Try using another Linq method like `Any` to check your `IsValid` condition

```
 return !Validation.GetHasError(obj) &&
            !LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(obj)
            .OfType<DependencyObject>()
            .Any(child => !IsValid(child));
```